# After installing cordova-plugin-screen-orientation npx cap sync does not work anymore

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I tried to install cordova-plugin-screen-orientation to control screen orientation for my ios app. But after installing this plugin it seems that npx cap sync just hangs and do not work. There is no progress bar no nothing. I can't seem find an issue similar to what happened on my end that is why maybe anyone experienced this.

I am using Apple M2 Mac chip with 16gb RAM.

EDIT:

It synced after 1100seconds or almost 18minutes, the issue is I can't wait that long each time I update the app. Has anyone experienced this know a possible fix?

Comment: it's taking just a few seconds in my case, is your CocoaPods version up to date? what do you get if you type `pod repo list`?

Comment: It's weird on my end it takes a few seconds after booting up mac after a few minutes it starts to take longer and longer times. But everytime I resstart it just takes lesser time during boot and takes more time overtime